# SQL - How do you perform a comparison as a result of a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, case, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have an SQL query with a`WHERE`clause with multiple conditions joined by`AND`

I want to do the following check:

```
WHERE something AND WHERE x <> y
```

but only the second clause when x is not a certain value (in my case NULL)

In other words, if x is not `NULL`, then I want to add the `x <> y` to the `WHERE` clause
The following code doesn't work - I don't know if it's a small syntax issue or whether the logic is not supported. If it isn't, does anyone have any ideas on an alternative solution?

```
WHERE something AND (CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL THEN x <> y)
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overthinking this. Just use boolean logic:

```
WHERE something AND (x IS NULL OR x <> y)
```

`CASE` is an *expression* and has to return a value. And on most database systems, the result of evaluating a *predicate* isn't represented as a value in SQL type system, so it cannot be the value returned by a `CASE`.

Comment: Just realised I never accepted this back in 2013. Thanks again for that. I don't know what I was thinking back then. I guess it's easy to focus on one path and not see the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE something AND coalesce(x,'some non-y value') <> y
```

This works best if you can find a constant value that you know will never match `y` for any row. If you can't, you have to use an expression to modify y, and that will be slower.